# Specify ordering of nested Phoenix form fields

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm setting up a form with nested fields, how do I specify the order of the fields so they're not grouped together.

I can use `inputs_for` to display the nested fields, however it displays them all at once. I want to display them in a dynamic order.

For example:

```
<%= inputs_for f, :apples, fn fa -> %>
  <%= label fa, :name %>
  <%= text_input fa, :name %>
  <%= error_tag fa, :name %>
<% end %>

<%= inputs_for f, :oranges, fn fo -> %>
  <%= label fo, :name %>
  <%= text_input fo, :name %>
  <%= error_tag fo, :name %>
<% end %>
```

This will group all the apples and oranges fields together for each nested association. So for 2 apples and 3 oranges it will show:

-apple

-apple

-orange

-orange

-orange

What I want is to display them something like:

-apples

-oranges

-apples

-oranges

-oranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data in from, it is in form variable passed into the callback function in [`form_for/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#form_for/3). So you can create a function that takes in that form, sorts and combines your apples and oranges, then renders them with your ordering.

```
<%= form_for @settings, Routes.config_path(@conn, :save), fn f -> %>
    <%= render_apples_and_oranges(f) %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your [view](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/views.html) file define function `render_apples_and_oranges\1`

```
  def apples_and_oranges(%{data: %{apples: apples, oranges: oranges}} = form) do
    # Sort and combine apples and oranges
    render("apples_oranges_field_template.html", form: form, apples_and_oranges: sorted_apples_and_oranges)
  end
```

And then create new template for rendering the apples and oranges:

```
<%= for field <- @fields do %>
    <%= text_input(@form, field.name, value: field.value %>
<% end %>
```